# Adding an extra step in checkout process in Magento 2.0.7

Tags: checkout, magento-2.0.7

I am developing a website http://Genericmedsstore.com/ similar to E comerce site

**Before checkout page I need an extra page "Medical Condition" who takes few information and one file (Medical Prescription) from the customer same as ADC(alldaychemist)**

My Magento version is 2.0.7 and Used Theme is Porto.

Answer (score 0):

You can find descriptive steps on : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html#create-the-view-part-of-the-checkout-step-component

Follow the page step by step.